# Convert hourly data to daily data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

We have two matrices. Name one of them "Date", And another name is "Data"
There are several columns in the Date matrix included:

```
year month day julusi hour
1951    1   1   1   0
1951    1   1   1   3
1951    1   1   1   6
1951    1   1   1   9
1951    1   1   1   12
1951    1   1   1   15
1951    1   1   1   18
1951    1   1   1   21
1951    1   2   2   0
1951    1   2   2   3
1951    1   2   2   6
1951    1   2   2   9
1951    1   2   2   12
1951    1   2   2   15
1951    1   2   2   18
1951    1   2   2   21
....    .   .   .    .
....    .   .   .    .
1951    12  30  364 0
1951    12  30  364 3
1951    12  30  364 6
1951    12  30  364 9
1951    12  30  364 12
1951    12  30  364 15
1951    12  30  364 18
1951    12  30  364 21
1951    12  31  365 0
1951    12  31  365 3
1951    12  31  365 6
1951    12  31  365 9
1951    12  31  365 12
1951    12  31  365 15
1951    12  31  365 18
1951    12  31  365 21
....    ..   .   ..  .
2018    12  31  365 0
2018    12  31  365 3
2018    12  31  365 6
2018    12  31  365 9
2018    12  31  365 12
2018    12  31  365 15
2018    12  31  365 18
2018    12  31  365 21
```

In my Data matrix, there are 410 columns(198696*410).The size of my Date matrices is equal. "198696*1". I want to convert the "Data Matrix on basis the Date Matrix to daily data
I use the following code

```
N=0;
for year=1951:2018;
for Juliusi=1:365;
cxa=(Date(:,4)==Juliusi);
cxb=(Date(:,1)==year);
a=cxa & cxb;
N=N+1;
dayy(N,:)=nanmean(Data(a,:));
end;end;
```

The conversion result is correct, but the size of the matrix is not the same
198696/8=24837 is correct but my matrix 24820 is incorrect
Where is the problem?
What to do to consider leap days?

Comment: Could you please provide your `Date` matrix, i.e. the actual `198696 x 1` matrix? Because there is some `365` in your loop. Do you take leap years into account?

Comment: You said your date matrix only has one column, but showed it with 5? Please provide a [mcve], the data is arbitrary, you should be able to give us a small runnable example.

Comment: The question was edited

Comment: You use `nanmean` so it will average x rows into 1 row. What did you expect ?

Comment: Certainly, 24837 is the correct number of days, since these are 68 years (each 365 days) + 17 leap days. If I run your nested loop without data stuff, I get an array with 24820 entries, since you don't consider leap days. 25185 days is what you get, when you have 69 years. Since I can't see, how the data stuff might interfere with the actual loops, I have to ask: In your actual script, do you possibly start at 1950 (instead of 1951), or run upto 2019 (instead of 2018)? Nevertheless, in general, take the other way around: Iterate `Date` and extract the corresponding dates.

Comment: You edited the question, but failed to include a [mcve]. Please read that link, and give us something we can *run*.

Comment: Reply HansHirse: Start recording data from 1/1/1959 to 31/12/2018. As written in the loop؛ It runs in MATLAB. The result is dayy=24820x410 What to do to consider leap days?

Comment: reply obchardon: The data matrix contains the amount of precipitation that exists in 410stations; nan is used to equalize the size of the matrices

Comment: Add something like `nDays = datenum(year+1, 1, 1) - datenum(year, 1, 1)` at the beginning of your "year loop", and in your "day loop" iterate from 1 to `nDays`.

Comment: Reply HansHirse: Thank you.  You can replace the  loop. To see me؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I recently learned from Luis Mendo, that *[convolution is the key to success](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67646/chain-reaction-of-bombs/67650#67650)*, I came up with the following idea: If your data is complete, i.e. you can guarantee, that there are always 8 entries for each day, you can just simply use the following approach:

```matlab
% Some test data.
Date = [
1951    1   1   1   0;
1951    1   1   1   3;
1951    1   1   1   6;
1951    1   1   1   9;
1951    1   1   1   12;
1951    1   1   1   15;
1951    1   1   1   18;
1951    1   1   1   21;
1952    1   2   2   0;
1952    1   2   2   3;
1952    1   2   2   6;
1952    1   2   2   9;
1952    1   2   2   12;
1952    1   2   2   15;
1952    1   2   2   18;
1952    1   2   2   21]

% Temporary result for convolution.
temp = conv2(Date, ones(8, 1)) / 8;

% Extract values of interest.
dayy = temp(8:8:end, :)
```

Output:

```
Date =
   1951      1      1      1      0
   1951      1      1      1      3
   1951      1      1      1      6
   1951      1      1      1      9
   1951      1      1      1     12
   1951      1      1      1     15
   1951      1      1      1     18
   1951      1      1      1     21
   1952      1      2      2      0
   1952      1      2      2      3
   1952      1      2      2      6
   1952      1      2      2      9
   1952      1      2      2     12
   1952      1      2      2     15
   1952      1      2      2     18
   1952      1      2      2     21

dayy =
   1951.0000      1.0000      1.0000      1.0000     10.5000
   1952.0000      1.0000      2.0000      2.0000     10.5000
```

If you need the year and day information, then these could be obtained separately. But in your original post, these information seemed to be unneeded.

---

Just to be sure: I DO know, I used the `Date` matrix in my example. But since, `Date` follows the same format as `Data`, and you can easily verify the results of the wanted `mean` operation, I used it as an example.

Comment: Thanks.
Thanks for your guides. best regards