# Daily average of electricity load

Tags: matlab, neural-network, average, forecasting

I need a help. How to calculate daily average load for three different plants? My dataset contains  18000 observation, date with datetime format `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss` with 10min sampling and el.load. Input file is .xlsx loaded into table in workspace. Need daily average for each dayt to improve net effectivity. Thank you!

[image: input data]

date,temperature,sum_of_three_plants,plant1,plant2,plant3
for example day 19.10.2018 - average 12kW and so on is it possible ?

Comment: Can you share a small data sample?

Comment: Please have a look at [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55164142/11089932). It's quite the same problem you have. You only have to adapt the convolution kernel (144 instead of 8), and the starting point of the value extraction depending on the time of your first measurement. Unfortunately, I don't have time right now to further elaborate on this. :-(

Comment: there is a method retime, avg=retime(r,'Daily','mean'); where r is a timetable, the problem is solved but how to include that parameter in input matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `matrix` like this (hour is irrelevant):

```
el_consump=["01.01.2019", "hh:mm:ss", 50;
    "02.01.2019", "hh:mm:ss", 45;
    "03.01.2019", "hh:mm:ss", 55;
    [...]
    "31.01.2019", "hh:mm:ss", 31];
```

And you wan to calculate average consumption from this data set. You can do it with simple loop:

```
day_sum=0;
day_number=0;
for i=1:length(el_consump)
    day_sum=day_sum+double(el_consump(i,3))/(10/(24*60)); %The last part of equation is to convert 10min to whole day consumption)
    day_number=day_number+1;
end
el_day_average=day_sum/day_number %calculating mean value;
disp("Average energy consumption is:");
disp(el_day_average);
```

And that's it - you have average daily consumption from defined period. As It use `for` loop, it doesn't matter how long is the sample, it can contain any number of days.